# UInavigationController Custom transition is not getting called

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uianimation

I'm trying to implement [MAOFlipViewController](https://github.com/nishimao/MAOFlipViewController) in one of my application. Everything is working properly, but as per my requirement I want to move back to 0 viewcontroller whenever user come to that particular view.

For moving back to 0 view I added following code

```
NSUInteger targetIndex = self.flipNavigationController.viewControllers.count;
for (int i=(int)targetIndex; i>=0; i--) {
    [self.flipNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

It's working fine. But it is not showing the animation.

How can I use the animation that is defined with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to my defauly pop navigation.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating my answer, so it can be useful to someone else too.

I used another custom library for flipping the view [Flip View](https://github.com/jaydee3/JDFlipNumberView). So to root view controller will work like :

```
-(void)popToRoot{

    NSArray *viewControllers=[[self flipNavigationController] viewControllers];
    NSUInteger cnt = viewControllers.count;

    if(cnt >= 2){
        UIViewController *lastVC = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:cnt-1];
        UIViewController *secondVC = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:cnt-2];

        [lastVC.view flipToView:secondVC.view duration:0.2 removeView:YES direction:JDFlipImageViewFlipDirectionDown completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.flipNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            [self popToFirst];
        }];
    }
}
```